# Trying to access key in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

I'm trying to integrate Chart JS into a project. I have some JSON data that is returned via Ajax using the following:

```
$(".symptom-graph").each(function(){
    Tygh.$.ceAjax(
      'request',
      fn_url('symptom_tools.ajax_symptom_graph'),
      {
        data:{
          symptom_ids: $(this).data('symptom-id')
        },
        callback: function(data) {
          $(".symptom-graph").each(function(){
            if($(this).data('symptom-id') == data['symptom_ids'])
            {
              //TODO: load up graph stuff here
              $(this).html(data['graph_data']);
            }
          });
        }

      }
    );
  });
```

The above code returns the following JSON data:

```
[{
    "x": "0",
    "y": "35"
}, {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "6"
}, {
    "x": "2",
    "y": "3"
}, {
    "x": "3",
    "y": "11"
}, {
    "x": "4",
    "y": "2"
}]
```

I'm trying to access each item in the array and pull out either the X or Y coordinate so that the `data: []` array in my Chart JS script has the each of the items.

I've tried the following to access either the Y or X coordinate:

`data['graph_data']['0']['y']`

`data['graph_data'][0]['y']`

`data['graph_data']['y']`

`data['graph_data'][0]`

Not sure how I'd loop over each one either.

Any guidance/solutions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Try to access like this data['graph_data'][0].x because your array is an object.

Comment: did you get the coordinate values from the ways you've mentioned and just want help with iterating over them?

Comment: @McBern is that not the same as `data['graph_data']['0']['x']` just using different syntax?

Comment: ['x'] that operator is for non-object array. the . operator is for object array

Comment: `data['graph_data'][0].x` - gives me `undefined`

Comment: @McBern That is [not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). The square brackets can be used for both objects and arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each()` function also, and use `jQuery.parseJSON(YourJsonDataSet)`

```js
var xArray = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"x": "0","y": "35"}, {"x": "1","y": "6"}, {"x": "2","y": "3"}, {"x":"3","y": "11"}, {"x": "4","y": "2"}]');

$.each(data,function(index, value){
    console.log("X - "+ value.x + " and Y - " +value.y)
   xArray.push(value.x);
});

alert(xArray.join())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked! How can I combine all of the X values into one variable separated by a comma width braces each side

E.g:

[20,10,40,30]

Comment: I have edit. Add values to array and use `array.join()`

Comment: "[As of jQuery 3.0, `$.parseJSON` is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native `JSON.parse` method instead.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)"

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery like this:

```
$.each(data['graph_data'],function(index,data){
  console.log(data.x);
  console.log(data.y);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate with plain loop statements like `for`, or as you use jQuery, utilize $.each.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.graph_data.length; i += 1) {
  // data.graph_data[i].x
  // data.graph_data[i].y
}
```

OR

```
$.each(data.graph_data, function(item) {
  // item.x
  // item.y
});
```

In modern browsers which allows EcmaScript 6, you can use `Array.forEach` as @Mamun answered. To see if you can use it in your browser, check it out at https://caniuse.com/#search=foreach

Answer (score 0):

However you derive that array as an object you can then iterate it.  Not sure if this does answer your question.

```js
var mythings = [{
  "x": "0",
  "y": "35"
}, {
  "x": "1",
  "y": "6"
}, {
  "x": "2",
  "y": "3"
}, {
  "x": "3",
  "y": "11"
}, {
  "x": "4",
  "y": "2"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < mythings.length; i++) {
  console.log("y:", mythings[i].y);
  console.log("x:", mythings[i]["x"]);
}
// access via keys
for (var n = 0; n < mythings.length; n++) {
  var keyNames = Object.keys(mythings[n]);
  console.log(keyNames);
  for (var name of keyNames) {
    console.log(name, mythings[n][name]);
    var value = mythings[n][name];
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```